# Issue with PromQL in Google Monitoring

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, promql, micrometer, google-cloud-monitoring

I have spring boot java application with basic metrics setup: micrometer, with stackdriver exporter to view metrics in Google Monitoring.
Counters/gauges work fine and can be easily viewed both in normal monitoring view and using PromQL querying, but when I try to access Timer count auto-recorded metric, I get this error message:
[image]

I wasn't able to find any info about such error, I know that micrometer-stackdriver implementation  exports Timer::count as INT64 type, is there a way to cast it to DOUBLE to avoid this error, or are there any other workarounds?

EDIT:
this is my code

```
    while (true) {
        Timer test = meterRegistry.timer("test.new.timer");
        test.recordCallable(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(1);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return 0;
        });
        System.out.println(test.count());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

and errror is the same:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the configuration steps or document reference for reproducing the issue.. Because when I execute the same query I’m not getting any errors.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Measure any process using micrometer Timer, use micrometer-registry-stackdriver to send it to google monitoring. If I try this timer_count query in normal builder it visualizes perfectly fine, but in PromQL query I get this error

Comment: I updated the question description, it's just simple test code with autowired MeterRegistry